# Storing User Credentials in a Mobile App (iOS/Android)

Tags: android, ios, authentication, access-token, refresh-token

In one of our Mobile Apps (React Native) we have a requirement to automatically refresh the API token once it expires. Our authentication provider does not support OAuth/OpenID. Therefore to facilitate this requirement the app is storing user’s credentials in the device, under both iOS and Android. It uses the standard keychain/keystore mechanisms provided the respective OS to store the credentials.

However, our Pen Testers have marked this as a risk and suggested to encrypt the credentials before storing them in the device's secure storage to have an added layer of complexity (OAuth/Open ID was their first choice).

We have multiple question on this,

1. Since we have Jail Breaking a=protection on is it really a problem store credential in KeyChain?
2. Is this a standard procedure followed in Mobile Development when OAuth like refresh tokens /auth code grants are not available to use
3. Is there a different approach we can usilise?
4. If we decide to encrypt as per pen testers' recommendation, there is an issue in deciding a place to store the encryption key. No point in storing it in the keychain or as it defeats the purpose. What would be the other places safe to keep the encryption key

Comment: Point 4 is precisely correct and why your pen testers are wrong. An extra layer of encryption will do very little, since you need to store the key somewhere and if an attacker is capable of getting the encrypted credential out of the keychain then they can also get the encryption key. To obtain the credential from the keychain, an attacker needs physical access to the device and the owner's passcode/biometrics. So, the "attacker" is probably either the device owner or someone who can coerce the owner into providing their passcode (through threats or legal powers).

Comment: They could, therefore, use that same technique to simply ask the user to provide the username/password directly

Answer (score 0):

Use the device's secure storage methods, such as the iOS Keychain or Android Keystore, to safely store sensitive data. Keychain (iOS) or Keystore (Android) are both sufficiently secure. For storing keys and other sensitive information, these offer a secure and segregated area.

You can also use the alternatives below:

**Remote Configuration**: During app setup, get private configuration information from a distant server. By doing so, you can manage and update credentials from the outside without changing the app.

Implement **biometric authentication** (facial recognition, fingerprints) to secure access to critical areas of your app. This increases security by another level.

Keep in mind that security is a continuous process and that no solution is 100% foolproof. It's critical to evaluate the particular requirements of your application, adhere to security best practices, and maintain aware of the most recent security dangers and protective measures. You can find and fix vulnerabilities in your mobile app by running penetration testing and collaborating with security experts.